# Open Source HTML5 Online Powerpoint Viewer

Tags: javascript, html, powerpoint, presentation

I wondered if anyone is aware of any online powerpoint viewers that are open source?

I've looked at http://www.accusoft.com/products/viewer/on-premise/info/overview/ which is the closest thing but it only works with web based documents, mine will be sitting behind an intranet firewall so now I've hit a blank.

I've tried ViewerJS but this doesn't support PPT.

If anyone could help me out with a js ppt viewer that is open source or has any other ideas then I would be very grateful

Regards Sam

Comment: Try hands on pdf.js but you would probably need to convert ppt to pdf.

Comment: Did you found anything about this ? I'm looking for the same!

Answer (score 8):

ViewerJS is the best if not the only one. Its source is on github https://github.com/kogmbh/ViewerJS

The only thing (as you say) is that you need to convert from ppt (microsoft) to odt (open document). I think that the latest versions of mspowerpoint has some option to save in an open format (odt).

If not, you can always use OpenOffice/LibreOffice Impress to create presentations in open odt format or to convert from ppt to odt.

Comment: Yup I'm also looking for the same answer as questioner of this question and viewerJs is the only most relevant thing i found yet but can somebody suggest best way to convert bulk docs in odt format first?

Comment: Wow.. viewerjs is >2MB.. :'(